# Using getJSON function to read from while loop data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, getjson

```
<?
    while ($row_previous_bill = $res_previous_bill->fetchRow()) { 
        $bill = $row_previous_bill[6];
        $bill_2 = $row_previous_bill[2];
        $bill_3 = $row_previous_bill[3];
        $bill_4 = $row_previous_bill[1];
        $hotspot_location = $row_previous_bill[5];
        $data[] = array("result_paid" => $bill, "err_code" => 0, "result_payment_details" => $bill_3, "result_time" => $bill_4, "result_location" => $hotspot_location);
    }

    $name = array("response" => $data);
    //sets the response format type
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    //converts any PHP type to JSON string
    echo json_encode($name);
?>
```

I am using the while loop above to get JSON format, then i use this

```
$(function() {
    //Set Url of JSON data. make sure callback is set   with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1/olem.app/tab/api/js_on.php?get=json&subscribers=incomplete";
    //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.$(username)
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        var html = "" + json.result_paid + "";
        //A little animation once fetched
        $('#js_inc_month').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 5, function(){
            $('#js_inc_month').html(html);  
        });
        $('#js_inc_month').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 5);
    });
});
```

to display `<div id="js_inc_month"></div>`up to this point i am getting undefined, how do i turn around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this:

```
$name = array("response" => $data);
```

You will have to access the data like that:

```
json.response[0].result_paid
```

If anything is unclear your could simply:

```
console.log(json)
```

in the response to see how the received object looks like.

Comment: my json data looks like this. {
  "response": {
    "get": "json",
    "subscribers": "paid",
    "0": {
      "result_paid": "subscriber1",
      "err_code": 0,
      "result_payment_details": "MPESA",
      "result_time": "2015-07-13 13:58:19",
      "result_location": "1-pkr HS"
    },
    "1": {
      "result_paid": "subscriber2",
      "err_code": 0,
      "result_payment_details": "MPESA",
      "result_time": "2015-07-11 13:15:26",
      "result_location": "1-pkr HS"
    }
  }
}

Comment: You shouldn't mix an array with an object. Makes it harder to iterate over. However the data you want lies in `json.response[0].result_paid`and `json.response[1].result_paid`

Comment: Either add `$data['results'] = array();` and then `$data['results'][] = ...`in your php (then iterate over `json.response.results` in your callback) or add `get`and `subscribers` as keys to your `$name` object and iterate over `json.response` with a simple for loop.